# Is there a way to get more detail about what changes are in "Operating System Updates"?

Tags: updates, appcenter

Whenever AppCenter tells me there are "Operating System Updates" available, I'm curious to know what is contained in the updates but when I tap on the item, the dialog that pops up is woefully lacking in information (screenshot attached)

[image]

How can I get more info?

Comment: I guess that the idea is for the feature to be **added**, not getting *yet another recommendation* about going to the terminal and *sudo apt-get upgrade* to get more details. If I'll have to go to the terminal every time to get more information about what's going to be installed, why bother having AppCenter telling the user that "updates are available"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

apt list --upgradable  will show you what it's upgrading along with versions

Answer (score 0):

I think your only alternative is to use the terminal.

Doing `sudo apt upgrade` will list all the packages that are going to be upgraded. Then, you can press n if you don't want to upgrade them or y if you want to.

---

Note: This will list all packages that are going to be upgraded. Not only the Operating System Updates.